# Scroll when tabbing through Itemrenderers

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, flex-spark

To allow you to tab through itemrenderers in spark you simply set hasFocusableChildren="true". However when you tab to a row/tile which is not visible, it doesn't automatically scroll the List.

What's the easiest way of making this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#ensureIndexIsVisible%28%29

My guess is use that method, use the selection change or other events on the list to determine when to call the method depending on your UI expectations.